# Choose the number of element per page (lines) showen automatically in a smart table

Tags: angular, smart-table, ng2-smart-table

I have a ng smart table

```
 <ng2-smart-table  [settings]="settings" [source]="sourceDemandeSoumise" (custom)="onCustomDemandeDetails()">

        </ng2-smart-table>
```

Everything is working perfectly but i just want to choose the number of lines showed when opening the page (3 or 5) .
Now i have 10 lines showed at the begining with the ability of chaging it manually to 5 or 10  or 25 or 100.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your settings you can congigurate the pages per page like this:

```
pager: {
      perPage: 10,
    }
```

If you need custom this configurations per page you can update your settings configuration like this:

```
    settings = {

    pager: {
      perPage: 10,
    }
    }


   constructor(){
    }


    yourChangeMethod(numberOfPages:number){
    this.settings = {

        pager: {
          perPage: numberOfPages,
        }
    }
    }
```